# Is there an entropy crisis in Spin Glasses?

Tags: condensed-matter, complex-systems, glass, spin-models

If you cool a material and avoid crystallization, you get a supercooled liquid and ultimately a glass. If you extrapolate the entropy of the supercooled liquid, at some point it intersects with the entropy of the crystal. This is known as the entropy crisis or the Kauzmann Paradox (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition#Kauzmann.27s_paradox)).

But all information I could find on the entropy crisis is for ordinary glasses. Is there an analogy of the Kauzmann Paradox in spin glasses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a very precise analogy.  See http://www.pnas.org/content/105/40/15263.full and the references therein for a detailed explanation of the many similarities between structural and spin glasses.

Comment: Thank you very. The paper cited is fascinating and perfectly answers my question.